# Error comparing values in "if" construct

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, if-statement, face-recognition

I am doing a face recognition project, and I want to compare the `x.label` returned value with the `ID` saved to database.
I always get an error in `if` condition comparing the ID with the x.label

```
  public int Predict(Image<Gray, Byte> testImage)
        {

            Emgu.CV.FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult x;
            if (testImage != null)
            {
                x= fr.Predict(testImage);
                pictureBox1.Image = testImage.ToBitmap();
                //MessageBox.Show(x.Label.ToString()+" "+x.Distance.ToString());

                OleDbCommand D1 = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID] FROM [connect]", DBConnection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = D1.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                   if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]) == x.Label)
                   {

                       OleDbCommand insert1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE OutputReport SET [Attendance]='yes' WHERE [StudentID]='109';", DBConnection);
                       insert1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show(" its working");
                    }
               }
                RefreshDBConnection();


                if (x.Distance < 69)
                    return x.Label;
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!!, The detected Face is neither recognised nor enrolled");
                return -1;
            }

            else

            {

                return -1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: ...what error do you always get?

Comment: Error 1 The name 'ID' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @mariam Is this ID coming from database??

Comment: That code will hardly do what you want. Since there is no block for the `else` part, only the `MessageBox.Show` is part of the `else` block, and thus you'll always return -1. Also, you have not declared `D1`, you're only trying to assign it a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you need to check x.Label value with ID column value in the database of MS-Access. For that you need to do execute reader and assign the value.

```
   public int Predict(Image<Gray, Byte> testImage)
        {

            Emgu.CV.FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult x;
            if (testImage != null)
            {
                x= fr.Predict(testImage);
                pictureBox1.Image = testImage.ToBitmap();
                //MessageBox.Show(x.Label.ToString()+" "+x.Distance.ToString());

                OleDbCommand D1 = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID] FROM [connect]", DBConnection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = D1.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                   if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]) == x.Label)
                   {

                       OleDbCommand insert1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE OutputReport SET [Attendance]='yes' WHERE [StudentID]='109';", DBConnection);
                      int i= insert1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
                   }
               }
                RefreshDBConnection();

                if (x.Distance < 69)
                    return x.Label;
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!!, The detected Face is neither recognised nor enrolled");
                return -1;
            }

        else

        {

            return -1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your advise but i still have an error Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' 
in the if (reader["ID"]==x.Label)

Comment: if x.Label is an int, then I think you'd be better off leaving the comparison as integers, not strings: `if (Convert.ToInt64(reader["ID"]) == x.Label)`

Comment: thank you so much for your replies, but it is not giving any errors but still not filling the data base column automatically

Comment: @mariam u mean `yes` is not inserting to outputreprt table?

Comment: @Sachu no it is not inserting

Comment: @Sachu any other suggestions ? please

Comment: @mariam did u check debugging? is it getting inside the if statement? Also  `yes` should be enclosed in singlequotes like `'yes'`

Comment: @Sachu yes i did, i tried both ways but i have found out that i should be updating the attendance column per the StudentID I have in the OutputReport so I used:
OleDbCommand insert1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE OutputReport SET Attendance='yes' WHERE StudentID='"+x.Label.ToString()+"'", DBConnection);
but stil not working.

Comment: @mariam so after this r u doning `insert1.ExecuteNonQuery();`? also r u sure the if condition is true and it is getting inside?

Comment: @Sachu yes i do exceute, yes it is true, sorry for late reply

Comment: @mariam can you post the code after the if statement?

Comment: @mariam u r getting the msg bos "its working" right..also `student_id` field is char or integer?

Comment: @Sachu yes I do get the message, Student_ID is column inside the database that save numbers and its type in access in database is saved as "Text", but I want it to work as when Student_ID=x.Label, I just used the value of 109 as a trial, because this value is saved in the Database already

Comment: @mariam can you change insert1.ExecuteNonQuery(); to int i = insert1.ExecuteNonQuery();. then msgbox the value of i and check what is printing.

Comment: @Sachu i got an exption : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: @mariam can you update my answer with your current code?

Comment: @mariam change it into `int i = (int)insert1.ExecuteNonQuery();` and check

Comment: @Sachu unfortunately same exception :(

Comment: @Sachu what is remote access option?